# Security risk to auto_prepend_file in Apache?

Tags: php, apache

I've implemented a PHP auto_prepend_file in Apache's httpd.conf file to password protect every page on the server. Let's assume the the prepended file is properly coded and secured. Are there any serious security risks to using an auto_prepend_file method? I'm worried this opens up  some sort of cross scripting attack or access can spoofed. Thanks for the help :)

In httpd.conf:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "path/to/application/auth/include/secure.inc"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your script `die()` s properly if the user is not authenticated (also after `header()` redirects, very important!) there is no fundamental problem I can see with this.

The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) doesn't give much reason to worry either (emphasis mine):

> The file **is included as if it was called with the require() function**, so include_path is used.

just be careful to **always use an absolute path** to avoid glitches with relative paths.

The only attack that I can think of is injecting a `.htaccess` file somewhere underneath the directory root that cancels the INI setting by setting

```
php_value auto_prepend_file none
```

so you should be careful not to accept file names for uploaded files from the user without filtering, for example.

Comment: Great thanks! Would `exit` also be more secure for killing the script vs `die()`? I never considered an .htaccess attack and it's a good thought.

Comment: @DeLonge it doesn't matter, `exit` and `die` are synonyms.

Comment: @DeLonge I added one thing to be careful about: Make sure you always use an absolute path for the prepended file.

Comment: yep already using an absolute path I don't forsee any issues with something like `H:\application\includes\etc`

Answer (score 1):

My apache log shows attempts to access my server like this one (IP masked):

> ??.??.??.?? - - [10/Sep/2012:05:16:29 +0200] "POST
>   /?-d%20allow_url_include%3DOn+-d%20auto_prepend_file%3D../
>   ../../../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd%00%20-n/?-d%20allow_url_include%3DOn+-d%20auto_prepend_file%3D../
>   ../../../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd%00%20-n HTTP/1.1" 301 895
>   "-" "Mozilla/5.0"

This is a clear indication that hackers are using auto_prepend_file and allow_url_include.